# Is there a generalization of Gauss's Law for enclosed dipoles, quadrupoles, etc

Tags: electric-fields, charge, gauss-law, vector-fields, multipole-expansion

Given the electrostatic field $\mathbf E$, its integral over a closed surface $\mathcal A$ is the total charge enclosed by it: $$\epsilon_0\oint_{\mathcal A} \mathbf E \cdot d \mathbf A = Q_{\mathcal A} \tag{1}\label{1}.$$ Now let there be given a a dipole field $\mathbf P$, so that $\mathbf D =\epsilon_0(\mathbf E+\mathbf P)$, the integral of $\mathbf D$ over $\mathcal A$ is the same as $\eqref{1}$ because $\mathbf P$ has zero net charge.

But is there an "integral" of $\mathbf D$ that reflects the detailed distribution of this net zero charge, that is something like $\text {Linear Operator}_ {\mathcal A}^1[\mathbf D] = \text {Linear Operator}_ {\mathcal A}^2[\mathbf P]$  where the $\text {Linear Operator}_ {\mathcal A}$ may mean *some kind* of integral of a vector field *derived* from $\mathbf D$ or $\mathbf P$. Of course, there can be a similar question for quadrupoles or higher order tensor distributions.

Comment: Does it have to be an integral involving the displacement or the electric field?  You could probably come up with something spiritually similar by taking the integral of the potential $V$ over a spherical surface of radius $R$.  Something like $$ R^l \oint_\mathcal{A} V(R, \theta, \phi) Y^m_l (\theta, \phi) d \Omega$$would given you enough information from which the $l$th multipole moment of the distribution could be reconstructed.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Yeah, maybe something like that. I had this vague feeling about a projection of P into some direction within the surface should be some integral of a tensor derivative of D. I am just disturbed by the lack of symmetry that we can express the total charge but not any of its details. Integrating the field a la Gauss of a single dipole always gives zero, there should be some other integral showing maybe not all but *some* of the details of that net zero charge ...

Comment: are you looking for the [multipole expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipole_expansion)?

Comment: @ACuriousMind No, I am wondering if there is a "derivative" of $D$ whose integral with some appropriate kernel is the enclosed $P$ with some other kernel.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this helps, but one way to do this would be to consider differentiation Gauss's Law. This gives the classical differential form of Gauss's law:
$$\nabla {\mathbf E} = \rho$$

Here $\rho$ is the charge density. Effectively if you can find derivatives of the field you can relate it to density changes. So even if net density in a volume is 0, a multipolar field will have a source in variations in the charge density.

A different approach would be to to simply compute derivatives of ${\mathbf E}$ and compute their flux integrals over a surface. Then again by differentiating Gauss's law you can get changes in charge.

$$ \oint \partial_l \mathbf{E} \cdot d {\mathcal A} = \partial_l Q $$
where A is the fixed closed volume

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).